# How to ensure a UIView with a transform fills a CGRect?

Tags: ios, algorithm, math, geometry, cgaffinetransform

I have a view `UIView` that by default has a `UIImageView` (the blue square in the included image) that is centered in this main view (the gray square in the included image). The main view has an added `CALayer` that serves as a border (window or mask — the yellow rectangle in included image) through which the image can be seen. The user uses gesture recognizers to pan (translate), pinch (scale), and rotate the image view's transform, but I'd like to give them the option of transforming the image so it completely fills the yellow border (all four corners), much the same way the iOS crop tool does (see attached gif). I've tried to figure out how I can calculate the correct scale factor, but now I'm wondering — is there some simple formula or function that can help me solve this problem?

[image]
[image: gif]

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773143).

Comment: You question is not clear with sample codes.